# How can I partition a matrix of coordinates based on the y value?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 2-by-30 matrix `v` containing pairs of x and y coordinates. How can I make another matrix to take all points of `v` whose y coordinates are positive?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you read the documentation on [matrix indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html), and specifically the part about [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1). I believe the solution you're looking for is something like this:

```
vSub = v(:,v(2,:) > 0);  %# Extract columns where the second row is > 0
```

Comment: This is a solution for a 30x2 matrix, and for non-negative `y`, not strictly positive.

Comment: @aschepler: Right you are. Corrected now. I guess I'm too used to storing coordinate values in columns instead of rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
vPos = v(:, v(2,:) > 0);
```

creates the 2-by-n submatrix you described.

Answer (score 0):

You try this simple indexing to extract positive values from both rows and merge both rows to form the required  all positive values.

> > V = randn(2,5);

V =

```
0.7873    0.3199   -0.3114   -1.0257   -0.2099
```

-0.8759   -0.5583   -0.5700   -0.9087   -1.6989

% first row

> > f_row = V(1,:);
> >
> > f_indeX = find(f_row > 0);
> >
> > f = f_row(f_indeX);

%second row

> > s_row = V(2,:);
> >
> > s_indeX = find(s_row > 0);
> >
> > s = s_row(s_indeX);

%merge both first and second row to obtain all positive values

> > posValues = [f s];

posValues =

```
0.7873    0.3199    0.6647    0.8810    1.8586    0.1034    0.1136    1.4790    0.7847
```

The above values are positive values in both  first and second rows.
Hope this helps?